# put custom taxonomy slug in front of their respective term slugs

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hooks, slug

I needed to register two custom taxonomies which partly share some terms.

The structure would look like this, when `commerce` and `crafting` are two different custom taxonomies:

- Commerce

  - Furniture
  - Garden
  - Walls & floors
- Crafting

  - Furniture
  - Garden
  - Something else

This of course results in some slugs to have slugs like for expample "furniture-2".

Can I force them to use their respective custom taxonomy's slug before their own slug? For example `crafting-furniture` or `commerce-garden` ? 
Is there a way to hook into it?

Comment: Install [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/).

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see, the plugin cannot solve the problem completely. Yes, it creates custom permalinks as I wanted it to, but it does not make the term slugs unique.